# How to Hide VPN Usage

Tags: networking, vpn, ip, ip-address

I want to be able to hide my vpn usage. In other words, I want to be able to use a vpn but websites would not be able to see I am using a vpn. Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SelekTor works pretty well for me. I just choose my exit node to be in the same country and usually it works. If it doesn't then I just find another exit node.